# Python: Start, stop, step

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following codesnippet.

I'm a bit confused, first, why do i have 2 as my step parameter, Is it because i jump from outside the dictionary, so i end up on total population?

Second: What in the world does i+1 do? Never seen it before? Would make sense if i jump from i (the country name) and then land on total population. But if that is the case, what's the point in having 2 as my step?

The code works as it's supposed to, i would just like to know how it works, in order to be able to benefit from it later in my own project.

```
result = {}
print(country_population)
for i in range(0, len(country_population), 2):
    result[country_population[i]] = country_population[i+1]['total_population']['population']

print(result)
```

country_population prints:

```
['Mali', {'total_population': {'date': '2013-01-01', 'population': 16352320}}, 'Ghana', {'total_population': {'date': '2013-01-01', 'population': 25855970}}
```

result prints:

```
{'Mali': 16352320, 'Ghana': 25855970}
```

Comment: _why do i have 2 as my step parameter_ I don't understand your question.  If you know enough to call it a step parameter, then you know what it does -- it increments `i` by 2 each time through the loop.  Are you asking why you would __want__ to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are missing a close right bracket in your definition of `country_population`. If you add that, your code does run as you state.

The reason you need a step parameter of 2 in your code is that `country_population` is a list of four items. The items are

```
'Mali',
{'total_population': {'date': '2013-01-01', 'population': 16352320}},
'Ghana',
{'total_population': {'date': '2013-01-01', 'population': 25855970}}
```

So you see you have information on two countries spread out over four items. The first to relate to Mali, the last two to Ghana. Items 1 and 3 are country names, items 2 and 4 are population data. So the code uses a step size of 2 to move from country to country. In each loop, item `i` is the country name, item `i+1` is the population data.

If the data could be stored differently, you should make a list containing two tuples, each tuple containing a country name and its population data. Then the structure of the data variable would match the structure of the data's meaning. In other words, define

```
country_population = [
    ('Mali', {'total_population': {'date': '2013-01-01', 'population': 16352320}}),
    ('Ghana', {'total_population': {'date': '2013-01-01', 'population': 25855970}})
]
```

This takes more lines and your analysis code would need to be changed, but the definition is easier to see and fits into a decent line length, and your analysis code would be simpler to understand.

Comment: I would rather suggest use a single dictionary with keys as country names and their data as list of values for the key.

Comment: @Austin: Yes, that would be better. I considered a single dictionary but thought that would be a more drastic change from that the OP has. Now that I think about it, that was a mistake. Thanks for the improvement.